# Are plane waves always transverse in Fourier Optics?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

In Fourier optics one decomposes the field into plane waves to find the solution of the scalar Helmholz equation. The scalar means that the electric field $\vec{E}$ is aligned towards only one direction.
The direction of a plane wave is given by the vector $\vec{k} = (k_x,k_y,k_z)$.
For transverse waves $\vec{E}\perp\vec{k}$.
But in the scalar case, the direction of the electric field is fixed. Does it mean that for the plane waves, used in the decomposition, in general, $\vec{E}\not\perp \vec{k}$?